# How to keep only final hypertuning trial/params to recreate a model

Tags: python, keras

I am using hypertuning with keras. That produces many files (1 sub dir for each trial, oracle.json, tuner.json).

I would like to run this in a docker container without a mounted volume/without writing all trial data to an external file system. But, I would still like to reuse all these trials when continuing/re-running the hypertuning the next time.

Is there a way to run hypertuning "out of the box" and discard almost all files after completion, except for maybe 1-2 files, which can be re-used again later? Which files would that be? Is it enough to keep the `oracle.json`, and copy it into the hypertuning dir the next time it's running? Or do I also need to copy the last trial folder with its checkpoints? Or multiple ones?

Of course I could "write" the best params to a separate json and create model manually from them, but for convenience reasons it would be nice to use the "out of the box hypertuning" every time, just skipping all the obsolete trials (given we already know the outcome) the next time around.